# Multiple gaussian auto-fitting in Python

Tags: python, gaussian, wave

The problem is to fitter on all my wavelength peaks a Gaussian in order to make a medium adjustment as accurate as possible

My question is how to make the Gaussian adjustment on all my peaks automatically without having to manually specify the coordinates of the peaks

For that, I realized the Gaussian adjustment of the brightest peaks, but I would like to generalize it to the following peaks. Subsequently, the Gaussian adjustment will allow me to obtain a polynomial adjustment fine enough to stagger pixels in wavelength

```py
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy import ndimage
import peakutils
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def gauss(x, x0, amp, wid):
    return amp * np.exp( -((x - x0)/wid)**2)

def multi_gauss(x, *params):
    y = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i in range(0, len(params), 3):
        x0, amp, wid = params[i:i+3]
        y = y + gauss(x, x0, amp, wid)
    return y


neon = fits.getdata(data_directory + wave_filename + '.fits')

neon_sp = np.mean(neon, axis= 0)
n_pix = len(neon_sp)

peaks_index = peakutils.peak.indexes(neon_sp, thres=0.05, min_dist=2)

### peals around the brightest peak
bright_index = peaks_index[np.argmax(neon_sp[peaks_index])]

delta_pix = 20
ind_min = bright_index - delta_pix
ind_max = bright_index + delta_pix

peak_select = peaks_index[np.where((peaks_index > ind_min) & (peaks_index < ind_max))]
peak_select_sort = peak_select[np.argsort(-neon_sp[peak_select])]

if peak_select_sort[1] > peak_select_sort[0] :
    ind_max = bright_index + 40
else : 
    ind_min = bright_index - 40

peak_select = peaks_index[np.where((peaks_index > ind_min) & (peaks_index < ind_max))]
peak_select_sort = peak_select[np.argsort(-neon_sp[peak_select])]

plt.figure(num=0)
plt.clf()
plt.plot(neon_sp)
plt.plot(peaks_index,neon_sp[peaks_index], 'r+')
plt.plot(peak_select,neon_sp[peak_select], 'ro')

### Gaussian fit
x = np.arange(n_pix)
xx = np.arange(0, n_pix, .1)


n_peak = 4
bright_index_fit = np.zeros(n_peak)

for i in range(n_peak):
    p = peak_select_sort[i]
    guess = [p, neon_sp[p], .5]
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss, x, neon_sp, p0=guess)
    fit = gauss(xx, *popt)

    bright_index_fit[i] = popt[0]

    plt.plot(xx,fit, '--')

bright_wave = [703.2, 724.5, 693.0, 743.9]
```

Comment: What is your question or problem for which you want an answer?

Comment: My question is how to make the Gaussian adjustment on all my peaks automatically without having to manually specify the coordinates of the peaks

Comment: It would be better if you edit your question to make the point clearer for anyone who might know the answer.